# Jquery-UI -AutoComplete Not Working With BootBox Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal, bootbox

Iam in a trouble by creating an '**Auto Complete Text Field**' in **BootBox** Modal.It does not showing any response when i search a keyword but works perfectly in normal pages(without modal).
   This is the script which i used to call a bootbox modal alongwith autocomplete function.

```
 <script>
  $("#bootbox-options-general").on('click', function() {
    bootbox.dialog({
            message : $("#myModalGeneral").html(),
            title : "Edit Job General",
            className : "modal-darkorange",
     }); 
  });

  var availableTags = ["ActionScript","AppleScript","Scala"];
  $( "#country" ).autocomplete({
     source: availableTags,
     appendTo:$("#myModalGeneral"),
  });
</script>
```

and Here is my 'MyBootBoxMoadal.html'

```
<div id="myModalGeneral" style="display: none;">
 <div class="row">
    <form method="POST" action="edit_job_info id="myForm3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="country" class="form-control"/>
      </div>
    </form>
 </div>
```

I had reffered a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sv9L7cnr/ which is working perfectly , but sadly it does not working with my **bootbox**.So is there any solution to make a AutoComplete TextField in bootbox modal.Working solutions will be appreciated.Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the autocomplete after the bootbox is loaded. Try this:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/spmsupun/pen/YaYMbE)

**html**

```
<div id="myModalGeneral" style="display: none;">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <form method="POST" action="edit_job_info" id="myForm3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input autocomplete="off"  type="text" id="country" class="form-control country"/>
      </div>
    </form>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
 <button id="bootbox-options-general">Click</button>
```

**css**

```
.ui-autocomplete{
  z-index: 1065;
}
```

**js**

```
  $("#bootbox-options-general").on('click', function() {
     var box = bootbox.dialog({
            message : $("#myModalGeneral").html(),
            title : "Edit Job General",
            className : "modal-darkorange"                   

      });
    box.bind('shown.bs.modal', function(){
        var availableTags = ["ActionScript","AppleScript","Scala"];
        $( ".country" ).autocomplete({
          source: availableTags
        });

    });

  });
```

The DatePicker DIV

```
 <div class="col-sm-6">
  <label>MBL Date</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <form:input path="mblOrMawbDate"
            class="form-control date-picker" placeholder="Choose Date" id="date-picker" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy"
                                value="${job.mblOrMawbDateString}" />
   <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="fa fa-calendar">  </i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow,It works perfectly.Actually here iam testing with simple array.Can you please help me out to integrate my country.json file as source in auto complete.

Comment: Can i see the file?

Comment: Yeah sure,it is just like [ 
  {name: 'Afghanistan', code: 'AF'}, 
  {name: 'Åland Islands', code: 'AX'}, 
  {name: 'Albania', code: 'AL'}, 
  {name: 'Algeria', code: 'DZ'}, 
  {name: 'American Samoa', code: 'AS'}, 
  {name: 'AndorrA', code: 'AD'}] under my src/main/webapp/resources/Countries.json

Comment: Actually i have a working code which is fetching from databse using 'ajax get' method.But in this case ajax is necessary?

Comment: yes, jquery can't access file by it self, and you have to use jquery `$.map` function

Comment: sure, i will check it out.

Comment: Hello Can you please tell me why the datepicker popup not working when i inserted autocomplete inside the bootbox?

Comment: yeah i have updated your answer with datepicker form(by mistake i have updated your answer instead of mine,sorry) and javascript is exact like your answer

Comment: Actually i found where the error is ,but i need your help to find the solution,i have used <script
 src="<c:url value="/resources/js/datetime/bootstrap-datepicker.js"/>"></script> for datepicker and <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> for auto complete, so the problem is datepicker alone working on bootbox not with autocomplete

Comment: okay first you have to edit your question or you have to ask this is as a new question. and can you put your whole code in codepen and send me the link and i'll check what's the error

Comment: finally i have solved that problem too,by putting jquery-ui.js link above datepicker.js link.Any way thank you so much for your support.